# Can you help me solve this block diagram?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, optimal-control, laplace-method

[image: Diagram]

Basically I need to find a transfter function (Xi/Xu) but I am stuck with this 'c', no matter what I do I can't seem to get rid of it.

Another point is that I don't see how I will get 'Xi' into the equation, since there is no feedback from it so none of the signals (letters) have Xi in them....

Please offer an algebric solution if possible. I don't ask you to solve everything just to get me started.

Comment: You have 10 equations in 10 unknowns ($a,b,c,d,e,f,h,k,p,X_i$) and want to find $X_i$ in terms of the known $X_u$.  Use your favourite linear algebra matrix solution algorithm, perhaps something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination .

Comment: I started an answer and got angry. Why do clueless instructors assign this stuff? I have never seen a block diagram this pointlessly complicated in any real application of control theory.

Comment: @Claude I was hoping someone could show me how to continue from where I started, because that's how we do it in class

Comment: @ALB well if you calm down I would still like an answer :)

Comment: My first instinct would be to isolate the feedback loops, since these reduce to $L/(1+L)$ where $L$ is the loop transfer function (product of all TFs going around the loop clockwise). But even this approach is of little use for this mess...

Comment: For $x_i$ note that it is equal to the sum of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @fibonatic, yes that's how I began my calculations as you can see on the right side of the picture. The problem is I don't see how Xi will ever appear on the right side of the equation.

Comment: @M.Wother I would not start with $x_i$, but with $x_u$ instead.